# What JavaScript code can I use to open in a new window, and not the window I previously opened

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I am new to JavaScript. Here is the scenario; I have an imagebutton that changes every 10 seconds and when I click it opens a link in a new window and when the image changes and I click on the new image, its link replaces the link in the same child window. However I want it to open the link in a completely new window. How can I make that possible please? (Preferably in the code behind Thank You)

This is the JavaScript code I am currently using:

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "open", " window.open(" + site + ",'open_window','myWindow','width=300,height=300,0,status=1,');", true);
```

Comment: The window name should change !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you specify "_blank" as a window's name, a new window will always be opened.

Answer (score 2):

The 2nd parameter of [window.open](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp) is the name of the window. In your code you are replacing the old window because you never change the name for the new windows.

```
 window.open(address1, 'window1', 'myWindow', 'width=300,height=300,0,status=1');
 window.open(address2, 'window2', 'myWindow', 'width=300,height=300,0,status=1');
```

**Edit:** As already mentioned, it would be easiest to use **_blank** as the 2nd paramter. **_blank** will always create a new window which will prevent you from having to change the window name for any additional windows.

```
window.open(address1, '_blank', 'myWindow', 'width=300,height=300,0,status=1');
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to give different names to the windows. Your's are always called the same:

```
 window.open(adress1, "NewWindow1", "width=300,height=400,left=100,top=200");
    window.open(adress2, "NewWindow2", "width=300,height=400,left=100,top=200");
```

Note that Opera will always reuse the first window.

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "open", " window.open(" + site + ",'open_window222','myWindow','width=300,height=300,0,status=1,');", true);
```

please notice `open_window222`

you must give different identifiers !

from MDN

> If a window with the name strWindowName already exists, then strUrl is
>   loaded into the existing window.